# Constructor chaining

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, constructor

I have following code:

```
    public MapReader(string fName) {
        FileName = fName;
    }

    public MapReader(){
        Console.WriteLine("Input valid file name:");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        this(name);
    }
```

Apparently this is Java approach, which is not working in C#. Is there any option which doesn't need added method for initialization?

Comment: I don't think this would work in Java either. Calls to base class or sibling constructors should be the first statement in a constructor body.

Comment: Isn't there a design problem? why do you provide your user with the second constructor? You are providing a method, it means it can be used, but then you generate this "invalid file name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in C#. You will have to set the property in the other constructor.

Ideally, you should separate out the dependency on the console.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you couldn' use that approach.
Try this:

```
private void setParam(string name) {
    FileName = name;
}

public MapReader(string fName) {
    setParam(fName);
}

public MapReader() {
    Console.WriteLine("Input valid file name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    setParam(name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with others that having a dependency on the Console is probably not best for this class, this would work:

```
class MapReader
{
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    public MapReader(string fName)
    {
        FileName = fName;
    }

    public MapReader() : this(ObtainNameFromConsole())
    {

    }

    private static string ObtainNameFromConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input valid file name:");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
public MapReader(string fName)
{
    FileName = fName;
}

public static MapReader FromConsole()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input valid file name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    return new MapReader(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite like the approach of having a side effecting constructor like that, you could simulate the same thing like this:

```
public class MapReader
{
    private string fileName;

    private MapReader(Func<string> fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName();
    }

    public MapReader(string fileName) : this(() => fileName)
    {
    }

    public MapReader() : this(() => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input valid file name:");
            return Console.ReadLine();
        })
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange way to solve the problem. The default ctor still has a side effect, so you haven't eliminated that problem. Essentially you are passing around a *deferred-execution* string when you could simply be passing around a string. Also, you seem to be missing a "return" in the statement lambda.

Comment: Yes, it is a strange way to solve a strange problem. My point was only that this would simulate the Java-behaviour. I should've pointed it out more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can to do so:

```
public MapReader(string fName) {
   if (fName == null)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Input valid file name:");
     fName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    FileName = fName;
}

public MapReader() : this (null) {}
```